# Nested loop creates duplicate entries when ran, cannot find issue?

Tags: java

When the code is ran the nested loop causes it to create occasional duplicate entries to the system, i have spent a while looking through this but still cant find what is causing this, would greatly appreciate any help?

```
for(int i = 0; i < subWorkItemElement.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
    Boolean test = false;
    WorkItemCommon existingChild = null;
    String summary = null;
    if(subWorkItemElement.getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeName().equals("workitem")) {
        // We know it's a work item - but is it in the existing list?
        Element childWorkItem = (Element) subWorkItemElement.getChildNodes().item(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < subWorkItemElement.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
            if(childWorkItem.getChildNodes().item(j) instanceof Element) {
                if(((Element)childWorkItem.getChildNodes().item(j)).getNodeName().equals("details")) {
                    summary = ((Element) childWorkItem.getChildNodes().item(j)).getElementsByTagName("summary")
                            .item(0).getTextContent();

                    for(String k : userInfoHashMap.keySet()) {
                        summary = summary.replace("${" + k + "}", userInfoHashMap.get(k));
                    }

                    if(childHashTable.containsKey(summary)) {
                        test = true;
                        existingChild = childHashTable.get(summary);
                        IWorkItem workItem = existingChild.getWorkItem();
                        System.out.println("INFO: The task with summary \"" + summary + "\" already exists. Skipping creation.");
                        System.out.println("this task is work item: " + workItem.getId());
                        //either check the tasks in the xml for updated details and then modify the existing workitem
                        //or just modify the work item without checking for updates
                        makeChildTask(childWorkItem, existingChild, childHashTable, userInfoHashMap, workItemHashMap, rtc, false);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(!test) {
            System.out.println("INFO: The task with summary " + summary + " does not currently exist. Creating.");
            makeChildTask(childWorkItem, thisItem, childHashTable, userInfoHashMap, workItemHashMap, rtc, true);
        } else makeFromExistingChildTask(childWorkItem, existingChild, userInfoHashMap, workItemHashMap, rtc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest setting a breakpoint and follow the code.

Comment: It's hard to follow your code without even knowing what exactly it is supposed to do and it's probably too much to explain here. So I'd suggest stepping through the code with a debugger and having a look yourself. Besides that you seem to iterate over the child nodes twice thus getting at least O(n^2) complexity. Try to fix that and you might even fix your problem as well (I guess you're processing some children twice).

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly (not sure what `makeChildTask()` does) changing an XML structure while iterating through the children list. While not necessarily incorrect, this can mean you get entries inserted while you process the list. Since you call the `subWorkItemElement.getChildNodes().getLength()` each time instead of cache'ing it, this might result in the length changing in between the loop iterations.

Comment: Very new to Java so havent ever done a cache before and not sure how to go about starting it if you could offer any suggestion that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this case by "cache'ing" I just meant creating a variable that holds the result, i.e.: `int howManyNodes = subWorkItemElement.getChildNodes().getLength();` and then `for(int j = 0; j < howManyNodes; j++) { ...`

Comment: ah thats great thank you, i shall try that and hope itll give the desired result

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue, still creates several duplicates after running through nest